# Custom View designing with Height more than Screen Height

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to implement an activity with height greater than screen height (1.5-2.0) times. It should be scroll-able(up and down). What would be the best layout to implement this? Any pointers will be helpful.
**Note : There is already a Scrollview inside center section.** I guess Scrollview can't be root view. Will Scrollview inside a Scrollview work?

Comment: Please have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to improve your question. We can't write the code for you, you have to show us what you've tried and then we can try to improve it or help you out.

Comment: Use the ScrollView widget to create scrollable layout in android. And don't forget to do some Google before asking the Questions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this will work or not but you shoud try it.
First make your bottom view visibility gone, assign onScrollEvent to your ScrollView as this

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()+view.getTop()));// Calculate the scrolldiff
        if( diff == 0 ){  // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
            Log.d(ScrollTest.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached" );
        }
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}
```

this code will detect when your scrollview bottom reached, when it reaches make your bottom view Visible otherwise gone programatically

same may be used for top view